# add_dependencies called with incorrect number of arguments

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to model my new C++ node as closely to the Actionlib Simple Action Server tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer(ExecuteCallbackMethod)) but I keep getting the following error when running catkin_make:

```
CMake Error at robot_arm/CMakeLists.txt:20 (add_dependencies):
  add_dependencies called with incorrect number of arguments
```

What could be wrong with my add_dependencies statement?

Only thing I can think of is that ${robot_arm_EXPORTED_TARGETS} is not getting populated such that catkin_make may think this argument is missing.  How can I confirm this?

My CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(robot_arm)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp actionlib actionlib_msgs)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS actionlib_msgs common
)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(ReceiveOrder ReceiveOrder.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
  ReceiveOrder
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_dependencies(
  ReceiveOrder
  ${robot_arm_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238201/add_dependencies-called-with-incorrect-number-of-arguments/) by [daalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/9331/daalt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2016-06-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial uses `robot_arm_EXPORTED_TARGETS` because the package `robot_arm` does also generate code for action files. Since your code doesn't generate any code for messages / services / actions / dynamic reconfigure the variable is not set. So you simply don't need this statement with your current CMake file.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2